# How to divide 11 wei by 2?

Tags: ether

Do you know what should be the result of dividing suppose:

```
11wei by 2(integer value) = ?
```

Thank you.

Comment: Nope. I need to divide smallest representation of ehter by two: 11wei / 2

Comment: Right, which in the real world results in 5.5, but that's not possible in Solidity, which is exactly what the linked question talks about.

Comment: @flygoing still some users find my question helpful because it straightforward as the answer provided

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The result of 11/2 in Solidity is 5, because there are no floating point numbers so the decimal is truncated.